# Regular expression in Java for Name not working

Tags: java, regex

I need to help in writing regular expression in Java for the following names:

```
name
name`s
name name
name-name
name`s name
name`s-name
```

I try to write following regular expression, but it not working :(

```
String  nameRegex = "[A-Za-z]+(-|,|\\s)?[A-Za-z]*";
```

I write following function

```
 public static boolean validateName(String val) {
    logger.info("in validate number");
    String  numberRegex = "^[A-Za-z]+(-\\s)?[A-Za-z]+$";

    if (val.matches(numberRegex)) {
        logger.info("in validate name of method validate");
        return true;
    } else {
        logger.info("in else  of method validate");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Its validations are:

1. name false    *it should be true*
2. 123 true    *it should be false*
3. abc022 true    *it should be false*
4. abc dsf true
5. abc-dsf true
6. abc'-dsf true    *it should be false*

my given pattern is not satisfied.

If I use this pattern `` "^\p{L}+(?:[-,\s`]\p{L}+)*$" `` end name without space it return false. It is also accepting name with digits.e.g. abc123

Comment: Did you try what you expression does match?
Which of your samples could you write separate expressions for?
Please show us some research effort.

Comment: I just tried ``^[A-Za-z]+(-\\s)?[A-Za-z]+$`` and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing "`" in your list of alternatives.
2. If you have only single characters in your alternation, use a character class.
3. You should make the complete last part match 0 or more times.
4. `[a-zA-Z]` is a very bad choice to match for names. What is with those poor people having non ASCII characters in their name? **Use `\p{L}` instead**.

So your regex could look like

```
^\\p{L}+(?:[-,\\s`]\\p{L}+)*$
```

`\p{L}` Is a [Unicode code property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that matches a single Unicode code point that has the property "letter" ==> **it matches any kind of letter from any language**.

I used also anchors `^` and `$` in my solution, it depends in Java on the method you use, if you need them or not. Please show the code, how you call the regex.

Comment: If I end name without space it return false. It is also accepting name with digits.e.g. abc123

Comment: Java ``String`` has a ``matches`` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

Comment: @m3nhaq You are right, it requires the string to end with a letter. If you don't want this, replace the + with a *. It will NOT accept names with digits.

Comment: @UrsReupke, wow, now that you write Java before String, I can't believe that I looked in .net string.